# Magento2: Move an element inside an existing element with XML Layout

Tags: magento2

I am trying to move the layered navigation to somewhere specific on the page.

Here is the layout XML at `Magento_LayeredNavigation/page_layout/1column.xml`:

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="content" after="-"/>
</layout>
```

And this works fine, it moves the layered navigation into the content area. However I want to move the layered navigation into here (`category.products`):

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
```

Changing the layout XML at `Magento_LayeredNavigation/page_layout/1column.xml` to this doesn't work:

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="category.products" after="-"/>
</layout>
```

Can anyone tell me the correct way to move an element inside an existing element?

Comment: Please accept an answer if it has worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can move things very simple by using XML.

In your theme or plugin file, respective `cms_index_index.xml` for cms homepage for example, just use this one-liner:

```
    <move element="register-link" destination="header.links" before="contact-link" />
```

You can use `before="-"` or `after="-"` to place the element before or after the destination. Both are **not** mandatory for `move` in order to work.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I suggest you this tool for easy customize the layout and template:
https://github.com/vpietri/magento2-developer-quickdevbar

By using this tool, we can find the layout handle quickly, with priority.
[image]

Follow the image above, product_filter_toolbar is the strongest.
So we will put your XML to that file: product_filter_toolbar.xml (May be different from your case). We should update the layout base on the layout handle, do not update on 1column.xml as yours.

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="category.products" after="-"/>
    </body>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below step to change position of layered navigation:

1) Override `magento2\vendor\magento\module-layered-navigation\view\frontend\layout\catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml` add below code after `sidebar.main referenceContainer`.

```
<referenceContainer name="category.products">
     <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnavs" as="catalog_leftnav" before="-" template="layer/view.phtml">
        <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.states" as="state" />
        <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderers" as="renderer" template="layer/filter.phtml"/>
     </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

2) `magento2\vendor\magento\module-layered-navigation\view\frontend\page_layout\1column.xml` add `category.products` instead of `content.top`

3) override `magento2\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Category\View.php` and add below code

```
public function getCatalogLeftNavHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('catalog_leftnav');
}
```

4) last override magento2\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\category\products.phtml
add below code

```
<?php echo $block->getCatalogLeftNavHtml(); ?>
```